# When I add new migration to project EF Core 2 still runs Initial instead of last migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 project and a MySQL database, I'm using EF with a code-first approach.

I'm trying to add new properties to `Models` and getting error when executing `Update-Database`.

Let's assume I have a model class `Test` like this:

```
public class Test 
{
    public int Id { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I'm adding a new property:

```
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Then I'm running `Add-Migration AddLastName` and `Update-Database`, I see in thew output that there's applying the first migration `Initial` not `AddLastName`. So the last error I see is `Table 'AspNetRoles' already exists`

Any idea?

Comment: did you delete migrations table records?

Comment: @RamyMohamed I was using Digital Ocean instance and now I moved to AWS, so my __EFMigrationHistory is empty, right

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have deleted migration records in database, so if that is the case then you will have to re-construct the database by removing it from your database and re-run the initial migration (only if you have just created the database without any useful records in it).
Another option would be to just remove those entries from migration which you think that tables are already in the database from the UP and DOWN methods and run the migration with only those entries which you think are pending and run the update-database command.